# Bubble sort implementation

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I wanted to decrease the usage of nested loops and the number of variables being used for sorting using the bubble sort technique. In the conventional code there would be two for loops or a combination of while & for loop. In that case, if the only reason for having the inner loop is to traverse back to the start index of the array till the most recent decremented length of the array size, I think this could be avoided with one "if" check under a single loop as illustrated below.

1. Would the implementation with the "if" check to replace the inner loop make the run time any worse compared to the inner for loop in the traditional algorithm? Is it actually needed to use a for loop instead of an "if"? In case the traditional algorithm is a part of the code which contains too many unavoidable nested loops and "if" statements for other implementation, there would be an increase in the cyclomatic complexity.
2. I would like to ask, when endianess comes into the picture, would there be an impact on swapping algorithm used in this case?

Here's the code:

```
void Bubble_Sort(int *arr, int size)
{
    int index = 0;
    /* pointer to array */
    int* temp = arr;

    while(size > 1)
    {
        /* Initial check if i has traversed up till
             last but one element of array
        */
        if(index == (size-1))
        {
            /* Set loop counter again from beginning*/
            index =0;
            /* Decrement the number of elements to traverse upto */
            size--;
            /* Set back pointer to start index of array */
            temp = arr;
        }

        /* Swapping algorithm */
        if(*temp > *(temp+1))
        {
            *temp ^= *(temp+1);
            *(temp+1) ^= *temp;
            *temp ^= *(temp+1);
        }

        /* Go to next element in array */
        temp++;

        index++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bubble sort, though a very inefficient sorting algorithm, has been optimized by esteemed computer scientists. The current optimal algorithm is (in kind of pseudo code):

```
sort (A, n)     // bubble sort array A[0..n-1]
{
    k= n-1;         // k holds position of last interchange. All higher elements are sorted.
    while (k > 0)
    {
        l= 0;
        for (j=0; j < k; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] > A[j+1])
            {
                tmp   = A[j];
                A[j]  = A[j+1];
                A[j+1]= tmp;
                l= j;
            }
        }
        k= l;
    }
}
```